# How to bind a jQuery event to dynamic content with AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Basically in my controller, I'm doing an `$http.get()` to load some html to set a "current view". My issue is that I can't figure out how to rebind the the jQuery event with this new dynamic content.

Right now, I've resorted to somethign like this:

```
$http.get('/someurl', {}).success(function(data){
  $scope.detailedView = data;
  // Now here comes the rebinding
  setTimeout(function(){
    // Use jquery to bind the new content
  }, 1500);
});
```

I've been looking for a solution, and anything related that I've found points to using a directive. I've looked into this, but I do not know how a directive would be used for something like this.

**Note** without the timeout, the bindings run before the dynamic content is actually in the DOM. I've also tried finding something that would be similar to hooking into something after the $apply would run but have not found anything similar.

Comment: What jQuery are you trying to use? What do you need to do?

Comment: I'm just trying to use draggable/droppable from jquery-ui, I want send a post request when someone is done dragging and use the response back in my ng-app

Comment: You'll need to separate your logic. UI stuff goes in a directive - not in a controller - and your callback logic with the `$http` in a controller or service. The directive lifecycle will ensure that your timeout shouldn't be needed. If it is, Charlie's answer below will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First should see if what you are doing with jQuery can't be done using angular.

Here's the most simplistic version of a directive that can be used:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" my-directive>Item {{$index+1}}</div>
```

```js
app.directive('myDirective', function ($timeout) {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $timeout(function () {
            /* element is a jQuery object when jQuery loaded in page before angular,*/
            /* otherwise is a jQlite object that has many of same methods as jQuery*/
            element.css({ 'border': '1px solid green', 'margin': '10px 30px','padding':'5px'});
        }, 0);
    }
 });
```

Here's a demo that uses a long timeout to generate data for repeated items that use the directive:

http://jsfiddle.net/AXYGL/

Comment: it seems a little.. inelegant, to have to rely on a timeout for the ajax request to finish, but it does do the trick.

Comment: simply one of the issues with angular and the digest cycle. Directives can run several times within a cycle and element doesn't exist each time if it is being dynamically generated. The timeout in directive has nothing to do with ajax delay

Comment: I ended up tweaking some things to make it more angular and then used something like this but without the `$timeout` and it worked. Thanks!